# R Nippon::kakasiでエラーになってしまう。

Tags: r

日本語のカラム名が多数あるので、カラム名をローマ字変換をしたいと思い
kakasiを使おうと思いましたが、使用例にあるように

```
library(Nippon)
data(prefectures)
regions <- unique(prefectures$region)
regions
# Unix-like operating systems
kakasi(regions)
```

を実行すると

> Sys.setenv(ITAIJIDICTPATH = .set.dict("itaijidict")) でエラー:引数の長さが不正です

と表示されてしまいます。Mac OS X を利用しております。

brewでkakasiをインストールして

```
echo "kakashiで苦戦" | nkf -e | kakasi -JH |kakasi -Ha
```

とすると動作は確認できています

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お騒がせしました自己解決しました
辞書を環境に設定すれば良いだけでした。

```
ITAIJIDICTPATH = Sys.setenv(ITAIJIDICTPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/kakasi/2.3.6/share/kakasi/itaijidict")
KANWADICTPATH = Sys.setenv(KANWADICTPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/kakasi/2.3.6/share/kakasi/kanwadict")


library(Nippon)
library(tidyverse)
data(prefectures)
regions <- unique(prefectures$region)
regions

kakasi(regions) %>% 
 data.frame(romaji=.) %>% 
 rownames_to_column(.,"kanji")
```